# Drawer layout cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-fragments, import

I am new to android and i tried a lot to solve this error but was unsuccessful please help me to solve this

My Imports

```
import tabswipe.TabsPagerAdapter;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;
```

---

Even After importing these. I am getting the following error-

```
DrawerLayout cannot be resolved to a type    
ActionBarDrawerToggle cannot be resolved to a type
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding the latest support library to your project.

```
    Right click your project > go to android tools > add support library
```

Clean your project afterwards.

Comment: which SDK version are you using ? try updating to the latest support library using SDK Manager i.e open the SDK manager and see if there is an update available for the support library.

Answer (score 1):

Try to prefix that your Drawer layout with the corresponding lib, because there is may be a conflict when you import your lib (I had this pb when I tryed to implement FragmentManager)

android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout myDrawer = ...

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the `support-v4.jar` in your `libs` and `clean` the project. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Import the support library in your project as the following [link](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html) describe

Answer (score 0):

Import the support lib to your projects..

For more information [Click Here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)...